# Gulf regions schedules appearing 1 hr out in iCalendar

Tags: imac, time-zone, calendar.app, meetings

I am being sent schedules from colleagues in Oman and UAE.  But they are appearing in my calendar 1 hr later than they should in iCal on my imac.  This appears to be because ical is identifying them as being sent from Arabian Standard Time (Saudi), not the correct Omani or UAE time zone.  The senders cant see anything wrong at their end. Other UK colleagues seem to get them through for the right time - although I am checking whether they have an imac or not.  This has happened before, but seems to have re-started since daylight saving kicked in. Schedules from eg Europe seem fine - but then Europe is also on DST and the Gulf Area isnt and I am wondering if thats the root cause. I cant see any controls that would affect things.  I have Time Zone Support on.

I can look at the incoming .ics attachment with a TXT editor and can see that it isnt correct.  But once accepted iCal sends a message back to the scheduler.  And that message has the correct time zone recorded in it.  So this is a bit weird.  I have tried a webmail system as well, and that also has the  incoming .ics file wrong.  I am beginning to think it may be something on the BTinternet server?
Thanks.

Comment: If the .ics files are being exported by users, then the most logical explanation, is the original calendar entry is incorrect.  These users would notice since more than likely their application is making the appropriate adjustments automatically per their system settings